# What is the electromagnetic wave propagation direction and significance of $\vec{k}$-vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Consider the electric field of electromagnetic wave to be of form $\vec{E}  =  E_°\cos(ax+bz) \hat{{i}}$  at $t= 0$ seconds. How to see in which direction wave is propagating? Does the value of $\vec{k}$ have a special significance with respect to this? How to find that if it is?

Comment: It's probably clearer to write the equation as $\mathbf E=(E_0\hat i)\cos(+)$. In my answer (below), put $\mathbf E_0 = E_0\hat i$ if you'd be happier with this.

Comment: Yes Sir this was very nicely explanation , i wrote some queries below regarding same please clear that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a plane sinusoidal wave propagating in the direction given by the unit vector $\mathbf{\hat k}$ is
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf E_0 \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\mathbf{\hat k} \cdot \mathbf r -\frac{2\pi}{T} t+\phi_0\right)$$
Here, $\mathbf{\hat k}$ is the unit vector at right angles to the wavefront, whose perpendicular distance from the origin – as you'll see if you draw a diagram – is $\mathbf{\hat k} \cdot \mathbf r$.
Writing, for convenience, $\mathbf k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \mathbf{\hat k}$ and $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$,
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf E_0 \cos(\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r -\omega t+\phi_0)$$
Expanding the dot product:
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf E_0 \cos(k_xx+k_yy+k_zz -\omega t+\phi_0)$$
Comparing with the wave you are considering, we see that

$$k_x=a, k_y=0, k_z=b$$
So the components of $\mathbf{\hat k}$ are
$$\frac {a\lambda}{2\pi}, 0, \frac {b\lambda}{2\pi}$$
The propagation direction therefore lies in the x-z plane, at an angle $\arctan{\tfrac ba}$ to the x axis.

We note that, since $\mathbf{\hat k}$ is a unit vector,
$$\left(\frac {a\lambda}{2\pi}\right)^2+ 0^2+\left( \frac {b\lambda}{2\pi}\right)^2=1.$$

Comment: Nice answer few things which i didnt get correctly : how do we prove that direction of propagation is same as kunit vector direction ? As for a 1-D case i can easily imagine at two times . But here i cant , and can you once write the general wave expression in terms of Ex,Ey ,Ez components instead of E_o ? Will the k unit vector will break into parts k_x when we are expressing as above? If yes why ? Why not k(unit vector )?

Comment: Haven't time to answer just now. Will have a go in a few hours time.

Comment: Yeah  sure no problem

Comment: (a) "how do we prove that direction of propagation is same as kunit vector direction ?" The key sentence in my answer is the first sentence under the first equation. As the wave travels the perpendicular distance, $\mathbf{\hat k}\cdot \mathbf r$ from the origin of a wavefront (plane of constant phase) changes. This can happen only by the wavefront moving at right angles to itself, that is in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat k}$ (b) "can you once write the general wave expression in terms of Ex,Ey ,Ez components instead of E_o ?" I don't know quite what you want here. (continued)

Comment: Do you really want $$ E_x = E_{x,0} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\mathbf{\hat k} \cdot \mathbf r -\frac{2\pi}{T} t+\phi_0\right) ?$$ and similarly for $E_y$ and $E_z$. Note that these field directions have nothing to do with $k_x, k_y, k_z$.

Comment: Understood fully Sir one relation can be setup between E° and k using dot product isnt = 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't know in which direction the wave is propagating (or if it is even propagating) just from its snapshot at one instant. You need to know how the wave changes over time.

Let's write the electric field vector at the position $(x,y,z)$ at time $t$ as $\vec{E}(x,y,z,t)$. Let us rewrite your equation as
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x,y,z,0) = E_0 \cos(a x + b z) \hat{i}.
\end{equation}
Suppose you measure the electric field vector as a function of the position $(x,y,z)$ at other instants and found a relation,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x,y,z,t) = E_0 \cos(a x + b z +\phi(t)) \hat{i}.
\end{equation}
That is, the phase in the cosine function is shifted by $\phi(t)$, a function of time, which satisfies $\phi(0)=0$. The wave form won't change suddenly in the next instant of $t=0$ (by physical intuition), and hence your measurement will indicate $\phi(\epsilon) = -\omega \epsilon$ at time $t=\epsilon$ for sufficiently small $|\epsilon|$. Here $\omega$ is a constant real number. [The negative sign in front of $\omega$ is put there just to arrive at simpler expression at the end. The symbol $\omega$ was chosen just to follow a convention.]

Now let us try to relate $\vec{E}(x,y,z,\epsilon)$ to $\vec{E}(x,y,z,0)$. By the above consideration,
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x,y,z,\epsilon) = E_0 \cos(a x + b z -\omega\epsilon) \hat{i}.
\end{equation}
We want to rewrite this as
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x,y,z,\epsilon) = E_0 \cos(a [x-v_x \epsilon] + b [z-v_z \epsilon]) \hat{i}.
\end{equation}
In fact, this is possible by identifying $v_x = a\omega/(a^2+b^2)$ and $v_z=b\omega/(a^2+b^2)$.
Then, we can say that
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x+v_x \epsilon,y,z+v_z \epsilon,\epsilon) 
= E_0 \cos(a x + b z) \hat{i}
= \vec{E}(x,y,z,0) 
.
\end{equation}
We can view this relation as the vector $\vec{E}$ we saw at $(x,y,z)$ at $t=0$ has moved to $(x+v_x \epsilon, y, z+v_x \epsilon)$ over time $\epsilon$.
That is, the wave is moving by the velocity $(v_x,0,v_z)$ around $t=0$.

The vector $\vec{k} = (k_x, k_y, k_z) = (a,0,b)$ is called the wave vector. We have seen above that this vector is related to the velocity of the wave propagation as  $v_x = k_x\omega/k^2$, $v_z = k_z\omega/k^2$. That is
\begin{equation}
\vec{v} = (v_x, 0, v_z) = \frac{\omega}{k} \hat{k},
\end{equation}
where $\hat{k} = (1/k) \vec{k}$ is the unit vector in the direction of the wave vector. We see that $v = \omega/k$. [I expressed the magnitude of a vector $\vec{g}$ by $g$.]

It is possible that your measurement of the electric field over time yields
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(x,y,z,t) = F_0(t) \cos(a x + bz) \hat{i},
\end{equation}
where, for example,
\begin{equation}
F_0(t) = E_0 \cos(\Omega t)
\end{equation}
for some real number $\Omega$. This wave (called standing wave) looks as if it does not propagate but stays at the same position while the overall amplitude changes in time. Note that this $\vec{E}(x,y,z,t)$ gives the same $\vec{E}(x,y,z,0)$ as in your question. Therefore, you need to measure the wave form at different instants in order to judge whether the wave is propagating or not.

Comment: Ofcourse i agree , by my question i was expecting people to assume its travelling , i was asking in which direction

Comment: To "i was asking in which direction", a short answer is "nobody can tell which.". Even if one assumes that the wave is traveling, they can't tell which direction it is propagating from the snapshot at $t=0$ only [i.e., from your expression $\vec{E} =E_0 \cos(a x + bz) \hat{i}$]. Two waves propagating in the opposite directions can take this same wave form at $t=0$. Both $E_0\cos(a x+bz \pm \omega t)$ give your wave form at $t=0$, but propagates in the opposite directions. One needs to measure $\omega$ including the sign through multiple snapshots over a time span.